# What does the command "\newblock" in bibliographies do?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I have been manually changing a bibstyle created with `makebib` to achieve a given look of the references. Since I ended up deleting a few `new.block` commands in the `.bst`-file and I realised that this removes the corresponding `\newblock`-command in the `.bbl`-file, I was wondering what LaTeX-command `\newblock` actually does.

I am using the `article` class at the moment but in general I am interested in whether deleting the `new.block` parts in the `bst`-file might cause spacing problems or other problems in some cases.

To be more precise, I do not see a difference between

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
  \begin{thebibliography}{1}
  \bibitem{Author2016Fancy}
    A. Author \newblock \emph{A Very Interesting Book}. Fancy Series, vol. 42,  \newblock Famous Publisher, 2016.
  \end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

and

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
  \begin{thebibliography}{1}
  \bibitem{Author2016Fancy}
    A. Author \newblock \emph{A Very Interesting Book}. Fancy Series, vol. 42, Famous Publisher, 2016.
  \end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I changed the question according to your comment. At the moment I am using the `article` class but I was worried about introducing problems with some documentclasses by removing the `new.block` parts in the `bst`-files.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the standard classes `\newblock` is defined as

```
\newcommand\newblock{\hskip .11em\@plus.33em\@minus.07em}
```

so it makes a horizontal space, if you use the `[openbib]` document class option then it is redefined to be `\par` so force a paragraph break between "blocks" of each entry,

Comment: That is very surprising because I cannot see a difference between the two versions using the `article` class. I added a MWE to the question.

Comment: @user93559 compare your MWE (now I have fixed it:-) with `\documentclass{article}` and `\documentclass[openbib]{article}`