# Changing bibliography style: one item at each line

Tags: bibliographies

Any thoughts on how I can change my style to have it in the following format?

[image]

Comment: Can you please tell us how you produce your bibliography at the moment? The solution will crucially depend on the bibliography/citation packages (`cite`, `natbib`, `jurabib`, `biblatex` ...) and the style you use (`\bibliographystyle{?}`, `style=?`). With `biblatex` you could try the option `block=par`.

Comment: Honestly, I don't have any favorite bibliography package. I'm open to any option as long as gives what I have in mind.

Comment: I think `biblatex` with `block=par` option will give what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: Just keep in mind that `biblatex` is completely incompatible with `natbib` or other BibTeX-based bibliography and citation packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `biblatex` standard styles and most contributed styles support the option `block=par` (or `block=npar`) that gives output very similar to your screenshot.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=numeric, block=par, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,pines}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Many BibTeX styles make use of a command called `\newblock` to separate blocks. If your style uses that command you could redefine it to obtain a break or (even better) use the `openbib` option of your document class (if supported). See also [What does the command "\newblock" in bibliographies do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/317942/35864)

```
\documentclass[british, openbib]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}
\cite{vangennep:trans}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or

```
\renewcommand*{\newblock}{\par}
```